# Why doesn't git merge the conflict-free changes automatically into locally modified files?

Tags: git, merge

Doing `git pull` periodically I notice the command sometimes ends with the error like

```
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:  
app/Ribbon.xaml  
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge
```

In this particular case I have one line modified in this file locally, and its new version in the repository has also one faraway line changed - there are no conflicts, no renaming, no changes in line endings, no submodules. So in this case I would expect git to merge the changes automatically without requiring me to `git commit` or `git stash`...
I know that git is able to merge changes automatically (it does this usually), but not in this case.

And the question: **what may prevent git from merging the conflict-free changes automatically** (into locally modified files)?

I guess, some data may be missed in my question. If so, let me know what else should be checked.

---

[27.JUN.2012 14:15] According to the hints in the answers, it is the normal policy of git to refuse merging any changes into locally modified files. Taking this into account I would rephrase the question to something like **how to enable git to merge the changes into locally modified files automatically**?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just natural behavior of git. Because your file isn't staged or committed, git doesn't really know what you want to do with the file. It's better for git to reject the pull rather than guessing what your intention is with the file. I usually stash my uncommitted and unstaged changes before pulling and then apply the stash after.

Comment: Well, with my SVN-based experience in the past I would leave only 1 option for git in this case: merge the changes to a modified uncommitted file, and leave it there. What other options git might consider? Discard the changes? BTW git doesn't care much (when pulling) about locally modified files if they don't have a newer version in the remote repo... Though in general you're right: git is able to merge the changes only for committed file, or the developer has to juggle around with stashing.

Answer (score 0):

Git works on files in it's repository, under the .git/ directory at the root of the project.

Git uses this repository for comparison when doing pulls and merges.

In your case, Git is smart enough to notice that you have made changes, but not added or committed them and thus git would not be able to work on them.

You get the message, **even though the changes are in separate areas of code** because you have not actually added the file to git yet and git doesn't actually know if there will be a conflict... until git 'sees' the file.  If you `git add` and then `git commit` the file, so it is in the repository then git can 'work' on it and if the changes are in separate areas **it'll be able to do that automatic merge** you were looking to see.

So it gives that message.

Your options are:

- Add and Commit the local files, then git can do Merges.
- Stash the local changes to save them aside and then Pull the new server files.
- Create a branch with your current changes - use checkout, then switch back to master and use reset.

Comment: well, you are certainly right, though I wish git had been smarter when handling locally modified files :)

Comment: Use git more and you'll find some nice smarts in git too :)