# SVN Maintain Dev, QA, and Production Branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

My team and I develop a project management system at work and we have three environments as depicted in the title. We are starting to come across a problem where we need to push small code fixes to production, but we have been doing development for the new team we are pulling in. We obviously don't want the new team's untested code going in, and picking out the small changes is a pain.

I know we need to do something along the lines of branching, and I have read up on tortoise's FAQs and I am pretty sure I understand it.

My question is, on our production server, are we able to do an update from a certain branch that was committed which contains the small code fix?

**EDIT**: On all of our servers (Dev, QA, Prod), we have the repository checked out so it's easier to push updates. If I create a branch on my local copy, then merge it into the trunk, can I then also merge that branch into Production's local copy?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory, using "Branch per feature" workflow, nothing will prohibit you

- Have separate DEV|QA|PROD branches in repo (or use trunk as DEV, one branch less)
- Create separate branch for task (f.e FEAT_X)
- Merge FEAT_X into *any* amount of target branches (and don't merge into some) and update server's WCs from merged-to branches later

but:

**Beware!** You can (under *some conditions*) be victim of [weird merge-errors on cross-branch merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221544/svn-merge-tree-conflict-wierd)