# Git. How to rebase in master? (SVN update analog)

Tags: git

I'm knew in Git, I used SVN for three years before.

I cloned a repo and made local commits without creating a branch. Now I'd like to 'get' changes from master, merge it with my local commits (if there are conflicts) and push the result to origin.

In SVN it would be  update -> merge -> commit. What is analog in Git for my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `git pull`. It will download last commits from the remote, and merge your work with it.

The `git pull` command is a macro for 2 different commands:

1. `git fetch` which download the latest commit and add them to the local remote-tracking branch
2. `git merge` which merge your currernt work (your last local commits) with the latest commits downloaded from remote

I suggest you to take a few minutes to read some basic concepts of Git. The [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a very comprehensive and interesting starting point.

Comment: thanks, I have a Git guide, but number of commands is still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The analog in Git to the SVN workflow is `fetch` + `rebase` (not `fetch` + `merge`)!

Moreover, Git cannot simply integrate remote changes into your working tree like SVN does. Git merge/rebase can only operate on a clean working tree!

The whole Git equivalent to SVN `update` would be:

- `stash` local changes to clean up the working tree;
- `fetch` remote changes;
- `rebase`;
- `stash pop` to reintegrate local changes back into the working tree;
- resolve conflicts;
- (if there were conflicts) remove the stashed state manually with `stash drop`.