# How do I set user permissions on GIT Repository?

Tags: security, git, permissions

I have setup git repository on a Linux Redhat machine.
Users are setup in .htpasswd. The checkin/checkout is done using http (Apache is setup for this).

How can i give read vs read/write permissions to these users on git repository?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is best suited for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com). [This question](http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine) might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, a set of perl script [managing authorization](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/authentication-vs-authorisation.mkd) to a Git repo.
You can [plug it on top of your apache](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite-gitweb-http-backend.mkd), which will do the authentication part.

As I mentioned in "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix)", a DVCS in itself has no authentication (and no authorization!)