# Does jGit support any of the following?

Tags: git, jgit

I reviewed the documentation at the web site and searched their forums but the following are still unclear so I just need a bit more info.  With jGit can I:

- Create new repositories
- add users / rsa keys to a repository

Or is jGit purely for client side operations?

Comment: What do you mean by "add users / rsa keys to a repository"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to better explain that.  I need to assign users to repositories and in doing so I have add their rsa public key so that git can track who is doing what.

Comment: Even native git cannot do that, what you want is gitolite -- but it works with native git. It would work with jgit if it supported the necessary hooks, which I don't know...

Comment: I know git client doesn't do that.  That's why I asked if jGit supported it.  If that means via hooks into gitolite or gitosis, fine.  I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGit supports the creation of new repositories: See [Running the JGit CLI](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Running_the_JGit_CLI) , one of the commands being:

```
init     Create an empty git repository
```

However, when it comes to "assign users to a repo", this is no longer a git issue, but an **authorization** system issue.
You need to add an extra layer to your Git setup (whether it is used with JGit or any other Git library) in order to manage the authorization.
I would recommend **[gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)**.

(and that doesn't include the authentication issue, which isn't covered by JGit or gitolite: see [all the issues you might have to cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757)).