# Why do you need Gitosis or Gitolite?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitolite

Sorry for my ignorance - but what is the gain of having either Gitosis or Gitolite.

I have a Synology NAS server running, but could I not just create a "bare" on any folder on the NAS?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer about "[authentication and authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757)": a DVCS (Distributed VCS) has none.

- Gitosis is dead (obsolete, not maintained).
- Gitolite is about [authorization, not authentication](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

You will couple that authorization mechanism with authentication ones, using ssh or httpd.

> However, it has to be an authentication system that is compatible with sshd or httpd in some form.
>   Why? Because the git client accessing the server only knows those 2 protocols to "speak git". (Well, the git:// protocol is unauthenticated, and file:// doesn't really apply to this discussion, so we're ignoring those).
>
> For example, let's say you have an LDAP-based authentication system somewhere.
>   It is possible to make apache use that to authenticate users, so when a user accesses a git url using `http://sitaram:password@git.example.com/repo`, it is LDAP that does the actual authentication.

Answer (score 8):

Main reason is access control. Git doesn't support any access control functionalities beyond repo-level access, and quite often something more fine-grained is needed, such as access groups, folder/file/branch/tag-level control etc.

You don't strictly need it for a lot of projects. However, for some, this is an absolute must.