# git(osis) and Xcode

Tags: xcode, linux, macos, git, debian

I installed (successfully) gitosis. I want to use it at my debian (rootserver) to access my Xcode projects (and merge, etc.). I'm able to clone the git repo with Xcode successfully, but if I try to push some (committed) changes, Xcode tells me "Choose the Remote to witch to push the changes" But I can't select any. I am able to push via Terminal.app, but that's not very comfortable. So why is Xcode telling me, there are no remotes available? I tried to add the remote manually (it is something like "gitosis@myserver.com:repositories/gitosis-admin.git"), I tried with ssh://gitosis@my..., but this dosen't even work with terminal.app.

So why is Xcode telling me "No Remotes available"?

Comment: Could we please forget gitosis already? It is not maintained for the past 3 years. Go with gitolite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358

Comment: oh! okay, thanks, I will change to gitolite and see if it'll change something!

Comment: You might still have that error message, and still have to deal with remote, but you will also have a lot more information and logs associated with gitolite itself.

Comment: Yes, I already thought so, but I really have problems understanding why git works the way it works (I'm getting into it, trying around since 5 days) and if I'm using an version which is that old, I think I know why everything is so unintelligible :)

Comment: Don't forget gitolite is an added layer on top of Git, an authorization layer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892969/why-do-you-need-gitosis-or-gitolite/10893091#10893091). You don't need it to access a local remote repo on your hard drive. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757

Answer (score 0):

Go to the organizer, click repositories, click yours, go to remote, click add remote, should be able to add it from there. should ask for verification and such. never used gitosis but that's how it works for git.

Comment: the remote tab shows my remote "origin" with the right location (the one that works in terminal) and the right username and password... but Xcode keeps to hide that remote, if I'm trying to push something... I'm really going crazy with git :(