# Can't ssh to the host after installing gitosis

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis

In the process, I issued  `gitosis-init <FILENAME.pub` with root and delete `/root/repositories`.
Then i did everything done.
But when i ssh to the host today,it reports

`PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
ERROR:gitosis.app:Configuration does not exist: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.gitosis.conf'`

I wonder what can i do? It's really urgent.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please use [gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309), not [gitosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893091/6309) (which is obsolete and stagnant for the past 3 years)

Second, if you follow [this tutorial](http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=277), the initialization step is supposed to create the `repositories` folder, which means you shouldn't delete it just after executing `gitosis-init`.

> Run this command to add your public key to the `gitosis-admin` project, that way you can check it out and configure git:

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```

> Now for good measure, make sure the `post-update` hook is set to executable. This sometimes doesn't get set up correctly with older versions of the `setuptools`:

```
sudo chmod u+x /var/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```