# Configuring gitosis to enable a user to create any repo?

Tags: git, gitosis

How can I configure gitosis (via the `gitosis.conf` file) to enable a particular user to create, clone or modify any arbitrary repository? That includes repos that do not yet exist?

I know you can add a user to have write privelages to specific repositories, but is this possible with all arbitrary repositories?

Something like this:

```
[group write-all]
members = richard
writable = all
```

I looked online everywhere, could not find a solution. My goal is to be able to just initialize new repos and push them to the server without touching the config file, so long as I am authenticated by my public key. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to switch to `gitolite`? `gitosis` is no longer supported. `gitolite` is able to handle wildcards / regexes

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is a feature only available with [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (along with [other features like VREFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358), over the [now obsolete gitosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893091/6309)).

It is called ["wild" repos (user created repos)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild.html)

> The wildrepos feature allows you to specify access control rules using regular expression patterns, so you can have many actual repos being served by a single set of rules in the config file.
>   The regex pattern can also include the word `CREATOR` in it, allowing you to parametrise the name of the user creating the repo.