# GIT usage in corporate world

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distributed Version  Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix)

I came across git some six months ago. Its nice, took me while for switching over from SVN to GIT. One thing that you will easily notice about git is the speed, it's lightning fast if you compare it to SVN. Now very well suited for opensource world, but what about its usage in corporate world ?

Against all advantages I see one major draw back when it come to corporate world.

Git spapshot / work area holds both source code and repo history. I understand even with SVN the entire repository can be copied but to look on to its history you will still need to connect to SVN centralized server. In git case since source repository is a part of snapshot you can look into the history / change to any state back in time.

How an corporate industry secure their source code with git(by security I mean source history and switching between revisions like SVN), any insights ?

Comment: This question is nothing about tortoisegit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix is the ultimate answer to your quetsion.

Comment: If code some how gets into the hands of unauthorized people, like directly copied / mailed. It can do more harm, since both code and its history is available. I am just comparing it with traditional SVN. In case of SVN you only have the code, not its history.

Comment: SVN just makes it a little bit more inconvenient to get history in an exportable format.  Theres [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.c.copy-revprops.html) that will happily copy all the history.  You could also use the `git-svn` tool to *clone* an svn repository and export all the history one commit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't see the logic behind: **why protecting legacy code is more important than protecting your actual work?** This is common delusion that central repository gives you more control on source code. The control is over as soon as first `checkout` is completed.

But:

- You can protect code from leaking somewhere outside by using protected VPN for your network connections;
- You can protect it organizational by making several groups of developers work on separate parts without having access to each over's work;
- You can protect it legally, by making developers sign NDAs and Code of Conduct;
- You can protect it by your IT infrastructure, making physically hard to take information away from your office.

Git is nice tool, it really makes developers' work pleasant. Use it.