# Create a new branch in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to create a new work branch in gitlab. I want to be the admin of that branch. Please, someone help me learn how to create my own branch in Gitlab and keep my projects on that work branch...

Answer (score 4):

From the command line:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

Comment: `-b` to create and switch to the branch_name

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) integration with [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) is mainly at the project level, to register users to project (only if said users have registered a public ssh key, otherwise, they won't even appear in the `gitolite.conf` file)

So for branch access, like **[personal branches](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/special.html#pers)**, you need to have access to gitolite-admin project, clone that project and modify the `gitolite.conf` yourself.

But even if you do, you won't see a graphical representation of that special Gitoite right in GitLab.
Even in its latest version (I am running a 3.2.0pre ff9a2e2, a commit from November 28th).

---

Personnal branches on  Gitolite:

> "personal" branches are great for environments where developers need to share work but can't directly pull from each other (usually due to either a networking or authentication related reason, both common in corporate setups).
>
> Personal branches exist in a namespace of their own. The syntax is

```
RW+ personal/USER/  =   @userlist
```

> where the "`personal`" can be anything you like (but cannot be empty), and the "`/USER/`" part is necessary (including both slashes).
>
> A user "`alice`" (if she's in the userlist) can then push any branches inside personal/alice/. Which means she can push `personal/alice/foo` and `personal/alice/bar`, but NOT `personal/alice`.

---

Where it gets complicated is that GitLab won't register '`alice`' (named after your public key `alice.pub`.
When GitLab receives your public key, it will create a public key file (stored in the `gitolite-admin/keydir`) named (for instance)... `alice_mail_com_123456789.pub`.

That is:

- alice email
- a timestamp (according to an edit by an "anonymous user": it is not, as I initially thought, a <del>generated random id</del>)

So you need, in your custom rules that you add to your `gitolite.conf`, to reuse that specific "GitLab" name.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @VonC. I visted https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/install/installation.md from that they specify to install some software package. Please check that link and let me know whether it is rite???

Comment: @Bathakarai that is a different question, namely: "How to install GitLab?". My answer was to point out that you can declare personal branches with Gitolite, without using GitLab. You actually can manage your repos without GitLab, while still using Gitolite. If you have issue installing GitLab, then ask a new question (specifying your environment and what you have tried, and what your error messages are). Otherwise, yes, you need to install packages first. That is right.

Comment: Okay @VonC, I am not clear about Gitolite. Actually what it is?? Send any link to learn abt it..

Comment: @Bathakarai good question. Gitolite is an **authorization layer**: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html. See http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/index.html#what and http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html

Comment: @Bathakarai As I details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757, Git itself has no authorization (anyone with an access to a Git repo can read/write anything). Gitolite is a layer which allows to control who access what. There is no GUI, just a script which intercepts git commands and your id, and allows or denies said git command. GitLab is a Git repo manager, a GUI to show the teams, the projects, like GitHub.

Comment: @Bathakarai  GitLab uses Gitolite for its access manager. Note that GitHub doesn't use Gitolite, and has its own authorization layer internally. Both projects (GitLab and Gitolite) are developed independently: GitLab uses Gitolite services. Gitolite doesn't even know that GitLab exists.

Comment: please provide the steps to get Gitolite file.

Comment: @Bat do you have gitolite installed?

Comment: when i install Gitolite the following error occures 
error: unknown option `dirty=-dt'
usage: git describe [options] <committish>*

    --contains            find the tag that comes after the commit
    --debug               debug search strategy on stderr
    --all                 use any ref in .git/refs
    --tags                use any tag in .git/refs/tags
    --long                always use long format
    --abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s
    --exact-match         only output exact matches
   ...etc

Comment: @Bathakarai ok that is a new question. Do mention the process you are using to install Gitolite, your OS, the version of your OS and of Git, and other relevant details. I will check that in your new question (rather in comments)

Comment: when i run "gitolite setup -pk bathakarai.pub" command i got "bash: gitolite: command not found" error message. Please tell me where the problem is??

Comment: Looks like Gitlab [no longer depends on](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/02/12/gitlab-without-gitolite/) Gitolite.

Comment: @jpaugh yes, that was for old GitLab pre 5.x

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is how to fork a project on gitlab. You do this by clicking a 'fork' link in upper right part of the UI

Answer (score -4):

Issue the following command in your terminal:

```
git branch yourbranchname
```

To check for how many branches available in our git project type:

```
git branch
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is terrible. Can someone format it. I can't tell where the comments end and the code begins.