# How to add my friend to combine my work on my git repository?

Tags: git, github

i would like to work with my friend on one project. So, for this i'm using git repo. But, i dont know how to add him to my repository on git. How to do this?

Comment: This depends on how you're hosting your repository. Is it on github or are you managing it yourself somehow?

Comment: If it is on github (as I presume it is from the tags you've used), you can add your friend as a "collaborator" in the settings tab on the github page for your repo.

Comment: Ask him to fork your repo, make updates in his fork, and submit pull requests, or add him as a collaborator to your repo. A simple google search returns the relevant help page: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in general, git itself has [no notion of authentication or authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309): if your friend has any access to your repo, like a simple network folder share, he can clone/push/pull to your repo directly.

Only the Git repo *hosting* server can add some level of control (like GitHub and GitLab where you can ask to [fork your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo), or you can [add directly a collaborator to your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository))