# Is there a better tool for performing merges in SVN (capable of using merge tracking info)?

Tags: svn, merge, dvcs

From [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613525/what-makes-merging-in-dvcs-easy) I gather that the strength of the DVCS, the ease of merges, comes from the fact that each revision knows its parents. Ever since SVN 1.5 came out [over 2 years ago](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/release-history.html), this is also available for SVN. So is there some tool which can use this information and make merges as easy in SVN as it is in DVCS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using p4merge
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html

Comment: We've got Beyond Compare, which is pretty good too. However I cannot find if p4merge can use merge tracking to improve results. Can it?